# Audio jack has fallen inside the body of semi-acoustic guitar, how to get it out and reattach it?

Tags: guitar, semi-acoustic-guitar

The nut on the outside was a bit loose, then when I took the cable out and put the guitar away, the jack fell inside the body. Not sure how I can get it out and reattach it to the hole without completely taking apart the guitar.

The guitar is an Ibanez AK95 so has f-holes on each side, which don't really seem big enough to allow me to root around inside the guitar.

Even if I did have to take the guitar apart to fix it, how would I go about doing this? I can't find anything on the net discussing how to take apart semi-acoustics or even acoustics, only eletric guitars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd get needle-nose pliers and pull the jack towards the hole, then insert the pliers *into* the jack and hold them open.  The pressure against the inside of the jack should be enough for you to pull it through the hole.

Comment: And perhaps a coat hanger, suitably bent, perhaps with a little double stick tape to help manipulate the jack into position from the inside. Gently of course

Comment: I did something like that. I used the pliers to get hold of it, then I stuck a small screwdriver into the hole and guided the jack along it until it came out of the other side. Then I screwed it in.

Answer (score 4):

I did something similar, using a piece of stiff wire with a hooked end to pull the jack through. Its also useful to point a lamp into the f hole so you can somewhat youre doing.

Answer (score -1):

Removing a jack socket from a semi-acoustic, I have used a 3" long rawlplug slightly wind the screw in to grip anchor with string to feed back through the f hole works!

Answer (score -1):

I successfully used an aluminum bent drinking straw and some cheap strapping tape wrapped around the end of it to make it both slightly bigger in diameter and to grip the inside of the plug.  I pulled the plug out through the f hole first by pushing the straw against each of the wire in view to find the one connected to the plug.  Once out, I threaded the straw through the plug hole and out the f hole.  I crammed the straw end into the plug hole.  Then I pulled it out the body hole, gently removed the straw, then pushed the straw through the f hole to put pressure on the plug so that I could screw the nut back on the outside.